# python extract list from json data to text

Tags: python, json

i have this json data https://pastebin.com/W422EtLn, returned form keywordtool.io api, need extract all string in text file, my acctual python code is this :

```
#http://keywordtool.io/api/documentation

def get_data(keyword):
    url = 'http://api.keywordtool.io/v1/search/google?apikey=[api]&keyword={keyword}&country={country}&language={language}&output=json'\
        .format(keyword=keyword, country='it', language='it')
    data = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
    pprint.pprint(data)

get_data('roma')
```

need output >

```
0 romano
roma 0 12
roma 0-2 man utd
roma 0 lazio 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to 'extract all string elements' from 'results' in the json:

```
outFile = open('output.txt', 'w')
for element in data['results']:
    tempList = data['results'][element]
    for dict in tempList:
        #print(dict['string'])
        out.write(dict['string']+'\n')

out.close()
```

Output:

```
h&m romania
h romadske tv
roma h&m
roma 2 bologna 3
(etc.)
```